# SQL Performance - SELECT COUNT vs SELECT id with LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, innodb

having a mysql database with innodb and I want to find the fastest way to check whether a row exist.

So is it faster to do:

```
    $sql5 = "SELECT id, value FROM pc_taxes WHERE id = :taxId AND client_id = :clientID LIMIT 1";
            $stmt5 = getaccessdata::getInstance()->prepare($sql5);
            $stmt5->bindValue(':clientID', $client_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt5->bindValue(':taxId', $taxID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            try {
                $stmt5->execute();
                $req5 = $stmt5->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $countTaxVal = 0;
                foreach ($req5 as $r5) {
                    $countTaxVal++;
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }

if($countTaxVal>0){
$rowExist=true;
}
```

or is this version faster on very large records:

```
$sql5 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pc_taxes WHERE id = :taxId AND client_id = :clientID LIMIT 1";
            $stmt5 = getaccessdata::getInstance()->prepare($sql5);
            $stmt5->bindValue(':clientID', $client_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt5->bindValue(':taxId', $taxID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

numRows =0;
            try {
                $stmt5->execute();
                $numRows = $stmt5->fetchColumn();


            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }

if($numRows >0){
$rowExist=true;
}
```

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I already searched but never found the SELECT COUNT with LIMIT 1...

Comment: count with limit doesn't really make sense...

Comment: Thought it would stop counting if one row is found? So it counts all records and only outputs one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really matter.

Please, do not ask performance-related questions out of nowhere. Instead, **bother with solution only if you have a problem at hand.**

For the question you asked, the fastest way to check whether a row exist is **to have an index for the column(s)** involved in the query. This is the right answer and this is everything you need for the task. While particular SQL syntax doesn't matter.

So, for your question you need an index like this `id_client(id,client_id)`

-- THIS is what makes your query faster.

Out of common sense I would say that if you don't need to *count* but want just a flag, then select that flag:

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM pc_taxes WHERE id = ? AND client_id = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = getaccessdata::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$client_id,$taxID]);
$rowExist = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

And for goodness sake, do not wrap your queries into empty try catch. You will deeply regret that day you started doing so.

Comment: id is the primary_key so additionally I should add an index to client_id? With the "goodness sake" part you mean that I should handle the exception?

Comment: if it's primary key, then you don't need additional index. and also you don't need LIMIT as well. As of exceptions, just leave them alone. Do not catch, do not "handle". Just let them go: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors

Comment: Thanks for the advices. Really helpful. In your example if $rowExist = 0  the row will not exist and if $rowExist=1 it will exist, am I right?

Comment: yes. you can use it directly in the condition, like `if ($rowExist) ...` - PHP will understand it all right